# Login to .NET app (MVC, EF) when application starts. No login form used

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Thanks in advance.

I'm developing an app for my company. Thing is, my boss asked me to do an automatic login, once the application starts.  He does not want a traditional login form. For this purpose, I've coded a custom module for login. My issue is:

I just can't figure out which Global.asax event should be used in order to trigger my custom login module(Or even if it's in Global.asax). I'm new developing with .NET , so apology if this scenario sounds trivial for all you.

I'm currently doing this. But I think it's wrong since Session_Start gets called twice sometimes.

```
 protected void Session_Start() 
        {
            try
            {
                User appUser=CustomLoginUtils.DoLogin();
                mapSessionData(appUser);
              
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               
                Response.Redirect("~/Error/Index?ErrorMessage="+e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: @eglease I've added my code. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You should not be using ASP.NET WebForms for new projects. You need to stop immediately, cut your losses, and restart with ASP.NET Core, otherwise you'll find yourself in a dead-end that's impossible to migrate to .NET 6. WebForms is over 20 years old now and hasn't seen any significant updates since 2008, and is really on its last-legs now.

Comment: @Dai yes well, I can't use .Net Core. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AgustinMoragues Why can't you use .NET Core or .NET 6?

Comment: Also, how does your "automatic login" functionality work, exactly? How are you authenticating the remote user and/or client software? (and `Session_Start` is not where you should be putting AuthX code - that needs to go in a custom `IHttpModule` that should be configured to run early in the request lifecycle, which means needing to tweak your `web.config`).

Comment: @Dai ok , I'll investigate that. My automatic login just hits the AD of my company checking whether the user exists. Nothing strange.

Comment: @AgustinMoragues That sounds like _Windows Authentication_, in which case **you don't need to do anything**, just configure Windows Auth in IIS (and disable Anonymous Auth) and that's it. No code required. (Also, if you're only checking to see if the user exists, you aren't actually authenticating the user, which means your system is insecure: - how do you know the request doesn't have forged headers or determine if they're a malicious user or not?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241229/discussion-between-agustin-moragues-and-dai).